# KoLite asyncCommand - understanding context

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working with the koLite asyncCommand -

https://github.com/CodeSeven/KoLite/blob/master/knockout.command.js

And having a hard time understanding it clearly.  Can someone explain how context is passed along. I get that this is passing the context -

```
return executeDelegate.apply(this, args);
```

But what is "this"?  When it's called via knockout like this:

```
<button data-bind="command: onClickCommand">click handler test</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you created `onClickCommand` using the `ko.asyncCommand` function:

```
viewModel.onClickCommand = ko.asyncCommand({
    execute: function() {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

`this` in your `execute` function will be the object that `ko.asyncCommand` created. This will let you do things like access `this.isExecuting` and `this.canExecute`.